# Using a Tooltip with Overflow Scroll and Z-Index

Tags: html, css, scroll, overflow, z-index

In a site I'm creating, I have a sidebar for directories. When hovering a node, I display a tooltip. I have the overflow set to scroll in order to keep the directories in their container. I need my tooltip to pop out of the container with overflow:hidden. I tried setting the z-index higher than the other elements, but it is still hiding the tooltip. Tried to post pictures, but I need a higher reputation first. Does anyone have a suggestion for this issue?

Comment: can u show us your code on jsfiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3w6kznac/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed here - http://jsfiddle.net/3w6kznac/2/

Do not set relative position of the item (to which hovering event is attached)

```
.tooltip{
        display: inline;
        /*position: relative; */ // remove this
}
```